# Random number generation from Cauchy 

Tags: java, random, distribution

I am a newbie in Java. I know Java has a random number generator function from Gaussian Distribution. As I have known from other question Java's built-in random generator is not that good because it doesn't take input mean and standard deviation of Gaussian Distribution which I need most. I am working on Genetic Algorithm. For the purpose of mutation I have to generate random number from Gaussian Distribution, Cauchy Distribution and Levy Distribution. Generator function must take input [Scale Parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_parameter) and [Location Parameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_parameter) of that distribution. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have those built-in. You will have to make you own functions, or find a 3rd party library that does.

Answer (score 0):

[CauchyDistribution](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/CauchyDistribution.html) from package 
[org.apache.commons.math3.distribution](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/package-summary.html) seems to what you want.

Java doesn't have this stuff builtin.

If you object to the jarfile bloat from that package, you'll have to roll your own, similar to [this example for Gaussian](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62).

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough the question is kinda old I'll try to answer as I was looking for the same thing and it could help the next person:

To implement a rng for an arbitrary distribution you need to know the following:

1. Generating uniformly distributed numbers in the [0,1) range is no problem
2. The derivation of a distributionfunction is the distribution density (e.g. the Gaussian Bell Curve)
3. The distributionfunction is (more or less) 0 at -Infinity and 1 at Infinity. Between those extremes it increases monotically.

Now you have to use these things (at least 1. and 3.) in the following way:

1. Calculate the distribution function (integrating the density)
2. Solve this equation for x
3. In the resulting function pass a uniformly distributed number as parameter to get appropriately distributed results.

Example:

Cauchy distribution:

f(x) = 1/(x²+1)/Pi

1. Distribution function:

y = F(x) = arctan(x)/Pi + 0.5   (it's necessary to add 0.5 to get a R -> [0,1] function

1. Solve for x

x = G(y) = tan(y-0.5)*Pi     (G is the inverse to F - usually F^(-1)

1. Now just put a generated double as y in the function:

   return Math.tan(rand.nextDouble()-0.5)*Math.Pi;

For the Scale and Location Parameter you only have to do the following:

X is your Gaussian (meaning: N(0,1) ) distributed stochastic variable.

Mean(a*X + b) = a*mean(X)+b
Var(a*X + b) = a²*Var(X)

a is your scale parameter, b is your location parameter.
Therefore generate a Standard Gaussian distributed variable and multiply with sqrt(scale) and add the location parameter.